# C++: Question on when memory is allocated and deallocated

Tags: c++, memory

Occasionally I am required to make some minor temporary fixes to C++ code that is maintained by another team. The following code is a contrived example based on what is in the code.

```
class A {
public:
    A() { }
};

class B {
public:
    B(A* a) {
        this->a = a;
    }

private:
    A* a;
};

class F {
public:
    static B* getB() {
        A a;
        return new B(&a);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    B* b = F::getB();
    // Do something using b here
    delete b;
}
```

My understanding was that in `F::getB()`, when object `a` is created, the scope of that is only within the method `getB`. And hence once the code exits from `getB()` the memory location where object `a` is stored would be invalid. Yet, I see multiple examples of this in our codebase.

Can someone please explain how the memory reference to `a` works even after the code exits `getB()`. And when is this memory location de-referened? Pointers to existing documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: The object does not survive the function returning, so either the constructor needs to make a copy or the pointer must never be dereferenced in the code. In your case it doesn't seem to be dereferenced anywhere, so it's not an issue other than introducing a completely unnecessary member variable... Only you can tell, if the pointer is actually dereferenced in your real code.

Comment: Thanks @fabian - In the actual code classes A & B have additional methods that act on the object.. Class B has methods that access methods of Class A (e..g a->func1()). Strange this is that the existing code is working.

Comment: For example code (and production code), don't name everything `a`. That's confusing.

Comment: Aren't you skipping over a `static` there? This looks similar to what you would do to obtain a singleton.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana It is not a singleton but similar. The example was made up (based on the existing code) in order to clarify my concept.

Comment: @PeteBecker Got it. For next time.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please explain how the memory reference to "a" works even
> after the code exits getB()

It doesn't work.  `a` is destroyed when `getB()` returns, leaving the `B` object holding a pointer-to-freed-memory, which is not a valid pointer.  Any futher attempt to dereference the invalid pointer will invoke *Undefined Behavior*, which could range from a crash to silent data corruption to any other behavior you can imagine (even including what seems to be "correct" behavior, but is really just "lucky")

If your code can run under Linux, I suggest running the program under [valgrind](https://valgrind.org), as valgrind will helpfully point out most references-to-freed-memory for you, which will help you track down the problem in cases where the undefined behavior is not readily obvious otherwise.  (Windows and MacOS/X may have similar tools)

> And when is this memory location de-referened?

The memory location will be de-referenced anytime some code use the `a` pointer to access the data it points to (e.g. `a->x` or `*a` or `a[0]` or similar).

Comment: Thanks @jeremy-friesner In our case, it seems to behaving "correctly". Will ask the devs to fix it lest it lead to problems down the line.

Comment: "seems to" being the key word there... :)   (in my experience, code invoking undefined behavior likes to "work correctly" until the day of the big demo in front of an audience, and then it will crash or do something equally embarrassing :) )

Comment: @tusht Are you sure your code has `A a;` like your example and not `static A a;`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  Yes, it is A a, only valid within the scope of the function.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Figured out why the code was working. The object "a" was stored within B, but all the functions of A that B accessed were during object creation only. So the reference was being stored but it was never de-referenced later. For sure not a good coding practice.